# How to store id(string) to objectId in nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//convert string to objectId

ctx.instance.schoolId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(ctx.instance.schoolId);

console.log(typeof (ctx.instance.schoolId))

Comment: can you please post your model ? are you using observers to save your data ?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(ctx.instance.schoolId)` you got `ObjectId` object.
So when you try `console.log(typeof ctx.instance.schoolId)` you got 'object'

When you need check if ctx.instance.schoolId is ObjectId you should use construction like this

```
if ctx.instance.schoolId instanceof mongoose.Types.ObjectId == true {
   // schoolId is instance of ObjectId
}
```

Comment: It ok but the code posted by me is correct thing . I already did it before like this , but now it's not working

Comment: So `typeof(ctx.instance.schoolId)` return you ObjectId string?

Comment: No, still it returns string. But when I did like this.        console.log(typeof(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(ctx.instance.schoolId))) it prints as object

Comment: It can be related to getter/setter in your model. How your model looks like? Can you just post `instance` Schema?

Comment: You are right there is a problem in schema, schoolId type is string kin schema i removed it ,now its working